# Symfony Cannot access EntityManager inside custom class/Method

Tags: php, symfony, entitymanager

The custom class dataUtils already created in symfony-1. I am trying to recreate the same class in symfony-5. when I try to access entityManager it shows "cannot use $this in a non-object context". I have attached code for reference.

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

class DateUtils {

    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public static function executeQuery($connection_param_name, $query, $values = array(), $connection = null, $charset_to = null, $i = 0) 
    {
        $em = $this->entityManager; // error (cannot use $this in a non-object context)
        
        if (!sizeof($values)>0 and stripos(strtolower($query), "where")!==false)
        {
            $filesystem = new Filesystem();
            $filesystem->dumpFile("log.txt", $query);
        }
        
        try {
            
            $connection = (! $connection) ? $em->getConnection($connection_param_name) : $connection;
            if ($charset_to == 'utf-8') {
                self::converToUtf8 ( $connection );
            }
            if ($charset_to == 'latin1') {
                self::converToLatin1 ( $connection );
            }
            if ($charset_to == 'latin2') {
                self::converToLatin2 ( $connection );
            }
            if ($charset_to == 'latin5') {
                self::converToLatin5 ( $connection );
            }

            $resultset = $connection->createQuery($query);
            foreach ($values as $key => $value){
                $resultset->bindValue($key, $value);
            }
            $resultset->execute();

        } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\ORMException $e) {
            $i++;
            if((strpos($e->getMessage (), 'Deadlock') !== false || strpos($e->getMessage (), 'Lock wait timeout exceeded') !== false) && $i < 12){
                $sleep = rand ( 1 , 5000 );
                usleep($sleep);
                return self::executeQuery($connection_param_name, $query, $values, $connection, $charset_to, $i);
            }elseif(strpos($e->getMessage (), 'Base table or view not found') !== false && strpos($e->getMessage (), 'st_user_value_berechnung_tmp') !== false && $i < 11){
                return self::executeQuery($connection_param_name, $query, $values, $connection, $charset_to, $i);
            }else{
                $sendMessage = gethostname () . ' - DataUtils:executeQuery: ' . $e->getMessage () . ' - ' . $query . ' - '.serialize($values);
                SystemTrayPeer::log ( 'err', $sendMessage, 'databank-errors', 2 );
            }
        }
        return (isset($resultset) ? $resultset : false);
    }
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

I also don't know how to use BasePeer and SystemTrayPeer class, which is in symfony1, to use in symfony-5. Should I need to add DatenUtils class as a service in service.yaml ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access properties of your class from a `static` method, that's why you are getting this error.

If you're rewriting your application you should consider what's the real job of this class. It seems that it handles too many differents jobs :)

Comment: Thank you @Mcsky, the real job of this class is to use the method to execute query by connecting to concerned database. Also, I will be rewriting some more methods which will be used for custom database table column selection/insert and so on.